# Toggleable series in a pivot chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-chart

I have a pivot table in which I show three different series, Ca, Na, and Li:

[image]

Now, ideally I want to have a toggle which lets a user decide which of the three series to show, without having to bring up the field list pane.

I saw something which might be of use [here](https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50fx/home/us-eslicer-to-select-value-fields-for-your-pivot-table-or-powerpivot), using a slicer and VBA, but ideally I don't want to include any VBA in the spreadsheet. If that's the only way to do it, I'll do it, but it'd be helpful to know that there's no "native" way to do it in Excel beforehand.

Comment: Just using slicer without macro should work (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d)

Comment: @MátéJuhász I suggest you make your comment an answer